# pandas add in regex in replace function

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to remove all forms(lower case/upper case, short forms..) of the phrase `'Thank you'/'thank u'/'thanks!'... ect` in my pandas replace function.

i currently just do hard matching which work but is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
df.text_col.replace(to_replace='Thank you',value='',inplace=True,regex=True)
df.text_col.replace(to_replace='thank you',value='',inplace=True,regex=True)
df.text_col.replace(to_replace='th(.+)u',value='',inplace=True,regex=True)
                                   .
                                   .
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the `i` modifier for case insensitive?

Comment: not in the pandas documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: @jxn Give us a hard list of what you consider to be a 'short form', otherwise this is going to be very hard to get right.

Comment: I found it, you can always put `(?i)` into the regex.

Comment: @Laurel, can you show example of it in code?

Comment: It's really not hard: `df.text_col.replace(to_replace='(?i)th(.+)u',value='',inplace=True,regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest enumerating all the cases of `thank you` you want to get rid of:

```
thanks_to_delete = '|'.join(['thanks', 'thank you'])
```

and then using the following one-liner for case insensitive replacing:

```
df.text_col.str.replace(thanks_to_delete, '', case=False)
```

Test:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
     'text_col': ['Thank you very much for your patience',
                  'I would just want to thank you for your patience',
                  'Thanks for your patience']
                })

df.text_col.str.replace(thanks_to_delete, '', case=False)
0                very much for your patience
1    I would just want to  for your patience
2                          for your patience
Name: text_col, dtype: object
```